# How can I add a not-maven-compatible jar file to a leiningen project?

Tags: maven, clojure, leiningen

I am trying to add [artemis](https://code.google.com/p/artemis-framework/source/browse/) as a dependency to my clojure app. But it doesn't have a pom file. So I can't install it to my local repo with or without lein-localrepo. Currently I have artemis jar file saved into `lib/`. How can I make it available within my project?

```
$ lein localrepo install -r repo/ lib/artemis-a609b2076aacc0ef5ecf0b390205d01bb88ceae2.jar com.artemis/artemis a609b2076aacc0ef5ecf0b390205d01bb88ceae2
$ lein trampoline run Retrieving com/artemis/artemis/a609b2076aacc0ef5ecf0b390205d01bb88ceae2/artemis-a609b2076aacc0ef5ecf0b390205d01bb88ceae2.pom from lib
Could not transfer artifact com.artemis:artemis:pom:a609b2076aacc0ef5ecf0b390205d01bb88ceae2 from/to lib (file:repo): no supported algorithms found
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies or network issues.
```

`lein-localrepo` doesn't generate a pom file:

```
$ ls -1 repo/com/artemis/artemis/
a609b2076aacc0ef5ecf0b390205d01bb88ceae2
maven-metadata-local.xml
```

Here is the relevant lines from my `project.clj`:

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
               [com.artemis/artemis "a609b2076aacc0ef5ecf0b390205d01bb88ceae2"]]
:plugins [[lein-localrepo "0.5.0"]]
:repositories {"lib" "file:repo"}
```

I am not using eclipse for this project.

Answer (score 3):

You can always add an jar to your local maven repository

[Guide to installing 3rd party JARs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

even if there is no pom available. You simply have to provide some informations like groupID, version  and artifact name.

After you have done this you can use it like any other maven dependency.

Otherwise you may have a look at "[Leiningen and lein-localrepo: How to create local maven repository for jar files](http://blog.cymen.org/2012/03/12/leiningen-and-lein-localrepo-how-to-create-local-maven-repository-for-jar-files/)" which describes a similar problem with netty and how it was solved using a lein-localrepo.

Comment: +1 this is one way to solve this problem. But I am looking for a simpler solution. Something that doesn't involve local maven repos. I would like to check in my jar file and simply have it available upon checkout.

Comment: I think your are using leiningen2. Leiningen 2 does no longer support `:extra-classpath-dirs`. There is some hack for this (I would not use it). You can use the `:resource-paths` to add jars you need. In your case you can add something like `:resource-paths ["lib/*"] ` to your `project.clj`file. As written before. This is a hack and I would not use it. The preferred way is to use the `lein-localrepo`.

Comment: Right, I am using Leiningen 2.2.0. I am trying to get the hack you mentioned to work now. The preferred way doesn't solve the problem, it is simply pushing it out of the leiningen domain. I don't like the idea of a new developer getting an error during or after running `lein deps`.

Comment: I tried `lein-localrepo` but it doesn't work. I've updated the question.